# What warrants a "Favorite"?

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

Is it ethical to Favorite questions arbitrarily? E.g. to favorite questions not for the question itself, but for great humor or something. This question is different from the one with which it is marked a "duplicate" because I'm asking regarding the ethics of using Favorites.

Comment: The other question also asks about the ethics of using favorites in non-standard ways, based on consequentialist assumptions.

Comment: @Nathan the other question's OP asks whether his unorthodox usage of favorites is somehow affecting question scores, user rep, etc. OP questions whether it's ethical to Favorite questions that aren't his favorite. There really isn't that much in common besides the titles of these two questions ("Standard purpose of favorites" & "What warrants a favorite?")

Comment: I'm asking whether it's ethical to favorite a question that I like not because of the quality of the question, but because of subjective factors, primarily humor.

Comment: As I pointed out, the common thread is in asking whether favoriting questions that are not in any normal sense "favorites" is "bad" in some sense. Here, "bad" is not defined; there, the actual rationale is not really given (and the question does not explicitly mention ethics, but it's clear that that's what it's talking about).